# Listview showing sorted data instead of how it is stored in database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-arrayadapter, simplecursoradapter

I am populating my *ListView* from a *Database* according to the code shown below in a *Fragment* which implements *CursorLoader.* Earlier I was using *SimpleCursorAdapter* for the same purpose but I had to change to *ArrayAdapter* for some reasons.

The Database have only two columns:

> _id(integer primary key autoincrement) and message(string not null)

The *ListView* is working fine but the problem is that the strings shown in the listview  are automatically sorted alphabetically and not in the order they were stored. Whereas I did not face this problem while using *SimpleCursorAdapter.*

Could anyone please tell what I'm doing wrong this time and how to correct it.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    String[] projection = {KEY_ROWID, KEY_MESSAGE};
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

    if(cursor != null){
        msgList = new ArrayList<String>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false){
            msgList.add(cursor.getString(1).toString());
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    } 

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.msg_list, R.id.list_textView, msgList);
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    if (mAdapter != null)
        listview.setAdapter(null);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: CursorLoader(...., String sortOrder)

Comment: The data from a DB is always fetched in an unpredictable order. You have to specify the column/s against which you want the data to be sorted and the order direction for each column (default: ASC).

Comment: @FrankN.Stein i treid using CursorLoader(...,  KEY_ROWID + "DSC") but it is throwing error no such column _idDSC.

Comment: **1** Mind the SPACE between the field name and the order direction. **2** `DSC` is not a valid direction. You mean `DESC`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein thanks. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I made an answer out of my comments, so that you can accept it and pull the question out of the Unanswered Questions bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data from a DB is always fetched in an unpredictable order.
You have to specify the column/s against which you want the data to be sorted and the order direction for each column (default: ASC).

Try using `CursorLoader(..., KEY_ROWID + " DESC")`